# Value not pass correctly to the controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I try to pass an `<td>` string value to controller on click.
This is my JS function:

```
function postCardNumber(elm) {                
    var CardNumber = $(elm).closest("tr").find(".card-number").html();
    alert(CardNumber); //Check, goes ok, display the correct <td> value number
    $.post("/CreditCard/ShowImage", CardNumber, function (response) {    
        alert(response); //the controller response is VB value "Nothing". Cant understand why?
    });
}
```

The Controller:

[image]

The Dibbuging value "Nothing":

[image]

Comment: Replace `$(elm).closest("tr").find(".card-number").html(),` with `{ cardNumber: $(elm).closest("tr").find(".card-number").html() },`

Comment: Now that the value in the controller: [link](https://s23.postimg.org/7t5g5dimz/nothing.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your action method parameter name is `cardNumber`. So when you send the data, send it with that key so that the value will be properly mapped to your action method parameter variable.

```
 var cardNumber = $(elm).closest("tr").find(".card-number").html();
 $.post("/CreditCard/ShowImage", { cardNumber :cardNumber }, function (response) {
     //to do : Do something with response
 });
```

While this code might be working for you, i strongly suggest you not simply sending what `html()` method returns.html method is to return the html markup of the element.So if you add a child span to this tomorrow, you have to come back and fix your code again!

If you simply want to send the cardNumber (a string value), you may either use the html 5 attribute to keep this in the div and read that value and send.

```
<div data-cardnumber="myCard number" class="card-number">
  <p>I can have any markup here</p>
</div>
```

Now to read this in your client side code,

```
var cardNumber = someSelectorHere.find(".card-number").data("cardnumber");
```

Assuming your `find(".card-number")` returns an array of only one item.

I also suggest you to always use the appropriate data types. If you are passing a numeric value, use a numeric type (`int`/`long`) as your method parameter to avoid unnecessary conversions later !

Comment: Now that the value in the controller: [link](https://s23.postimg.org/7t5g5dimz/nothing.png)

Answer (score 0):

You missed the name of the parameter in your Ajax-Request. Change

```
$.post("/CreditCard/ShowImage", $(elm).closest("tr").find(".card-number").html(), function (response) {
```

to

```
 var postBody = {
    cardNumber: $(elm).closest("tr").find(".card-number").html()
 };
 $.post("/CreditCard/ShowImage", { cardNumber: cardNumber }, function (response) {
```

Maybe its also required to use the `[FromBody]` attribute to tell ASP.NET that it can find the Id in the POST body, and not as URL parameter like normally the case. See https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api its described in the second paragraph how to use it.